# How to Add Multiple 3rd Party Forms to One Marketing Cloud Data Extension with AmpScript

Tags: salesforce-marketing-cloud, ampscript

I have been asked to figure out how to direct submissions from multiple 3rd party forms into one Marketing Cloud data extension.

I have the following built but instead of returning one record with the proper form URL, it's returning 2 duplicate records with FormURL A, no matter what form I test.

I'm new to ampscript and can see why this is happening, but am unsure of what to change?

Note: Please ignore the referrer lines, that's also a test but doesn't seem to affect the post.

```
%%[

SET @FormURL = RequestParameter("FormURL")
SET @FirstName = RequestParameter('name')
SET @LastName = RequestParameter("LastName")
SET @Company = RequestParameter("Company")
SET @Email = RequestParameter("email")
SET @ampscriptReferrer = RequestParameter("referrer")

IF @FormURL == "Example:FormURL A" THEN

SET @MIG_Test_A= InsertDE('MIG_Test_A','FirstName',@FirstName,'LastName',@LastName,'Company',@Company,'EmailAddress',@Email,'FormURL',@FormURL,'preURL',@ampscriptReferrer)

ENDIF @FormURL == "Example:FormURL B" THEN

SET @MIG_Test_A= InsertDE('MIG_Test_A','FirstName',@FirstName,'LastName',@LastName,'Company',@Company,'EmailAddress',@Email,'FormURL',@FormURL,'preURL',@ampscriptReferrer)

ENDIF
]%%
```

Comment: You will have more luck getting your questions answered about Salesforce on SFSE: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/ which is a sister-site to Stackoverflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are mistakingly using ENDIF instead of ELSEIF. Please try this code instead:

```ampscript
%%[

SET @FormURL = RequestParameter("FormURL")
SET @FirstName = RequestParameter('name')
SET @LastName = RequestParameter("LastName")
SET @Company = RequestParameter("Company")
SET @Email = RequestParameter("email")
SET @ampscriptReferrer = RequestParameter("referrer")

IF @FormURL == "Example:FormURL A" THEN

SET @MIG_Test_A= InsertDE('MIG_Test_A','FirstName',@FirstName,'LastName',@LastName,'Company',@Company,'EmailAddress',@Email,'FormURL',@FormURL,'preURL',@ampscriptReferrer)

ELSEIF @FormURL == "Example:FormURL B" THEN

SET @MIG_Test_A= InsertDE('MIG_Test_A','FirstName',@FirstName,'LastName',@LastName,'Company',@Company,'EmailAddress',@Email,'FormURL',@FormURL,'preURL',@ampscriptReferrer)

ENDIF
]%%
```

When using `ENDIF`, you close your `IF` statement, meaning everything after will still be executed. When using `ELSEIF`, you will only execute the code after `ELSEIF` if it meets the condition. In your case: `@FormURL == "Example:FormURL B" THEN`